# Simple scenario for using .prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

2 Questions:

1. Below, will [Code A](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp) and Code B have the
   same result?

*ADDITION* after reading answer of @Box9: **What about Code A vs. Code C?**

1. What is a simple, practical,
   intuitive coding scenario where Code A is
   the preferred technique?

### Code A: with .prototype

```
function employee(name,jobtitle,born)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
    this.born=born;
}

employee.prototype.salary=null;
```

### Code B: without .prototype

```
function employee(name,jobtitle,born)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
    this.born=born;

    employee.salary=null;
}
```

### Code C: with .prototype , nothing inside

```
    function employee(){}

employee.prototype.name=null;    
employee.prototype.jobtitle=null;
employee.prototype.born=null;
employee.prototype.salary=null;
```

Apologies ahead of time, I realize there have been other SO questions on .prototype and many web tutorials, however those explanations seem to be either overly simplistic or just technically over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, Code A is correct, while Code B is not.

To explain, we can think about `employee` from three different aspects:

1. **A "standard" employee** - the default set of values common to all new employees. It's the mould from which we create new employees. E.g. salaries for new employees start off as null.

   - This is the `prototype`.
2. **A "particular" employee** - say, John. He initially starts off with a null salary (from the "standard" employee), but he can get assigned his own salary later on. He also has his own name, job title, and birthdate which are unique to him.

   - The unique properties are assigned using the keyword `this` within the `employee()` function.
3. **Employees as a group** - blanket values that aren't stored for each employee, but for all employees at once, e.g. all the employees are from Company A.

   - This is setting a property directly on the function `employee`.

Now relating back to your two code examples,

`employee.prototype.salary = null` in Code A is correct because it is setting the starting salary for the "standard" employee.

`employee.salary = null` in Code B is incorrect because it is setting the salary for all employees as a group - i.e. it's not just a default value, but a *single*, blanket value for all employees. It doesn't matter that this code is inside the `employee()` function - the only difference the function makes is that it allows you to use the `this` keyword to refer to the "particular" employee that is currently being constructed as a result of calling `new employee()`.

Comment: Hmm I don't think I can edit it any more. I hope that wasn't overly simplistic or too technically over your head ;)

Comment: ...thanks for the clear answer....and your patience...after reading your answer, I added another part to my question....So looking above,  Code A and Code C are the same then? And Code A is just a conveniant way to inputing data into the objects attributes at the time it is being instantiated? Am I correct?

Comment: @indiehacker, keep in mind though that you typically don't need to set properties to null by default, since you can always check if `typeof someEmployee.name == 'undefined'`, and set values to undefined properties to define them. `null` isn't wrong but it's better reserved for situations where it has its own meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Code A and B will have different results.  Code A has a constructor for an object and adds a property to its prototype.  This means all instances of `employee` will have a field called `salary`, which is null.  As is the normal behaviour for prototype properties, if any of those instances write to the property, it will create a local copy for the object.

So, using Code A:

```
var e = new employee('Bob', 'janitor', 1978);
alert(e.salary);  // null

var f = new employee('Alice', 'teacher', 1976);
f.salary = 20000;

alert(f.salary);  // 20000
alert(e.salary);  // null
```

In the case of Code B, none of the instances of employee will have salary as a property, but the constructor will, e.g. `employee.salary` will exist, and be more like a static class variable in classical inheritance.  You might do that if you wanted to have a value available for all instances, e.g. `employee.RETIREMENT_AGE = 65`, but you would usually do that after the constructor, not in it (you're assigning the same thing repeatedly).